# Rate of convergence of an iterative root finding method similar to Newton-Raphson

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, roots, newton-raphson

We are defining an algorithm as follows:

> Let $f(x)$ be a function with a root in $[a,b]$. We define a series $\{x_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ as follows: $x_{k+1}=x_k-f(x_k)\frac{b-a}{f(b)-f(a)}$.
>
> Does $\{x_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ converge to a root of $f(x)$? If so, how quickly?

This seems somewhat similar to Newton-Raphson, and that doesn't always converge, so I'm thinking this doesn't converge either. But perhaps I am wrong? How do I show this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What a strange method. Unlike Newton-Raphson, it uses the same slope at every step; the slope of the secant through  points $\{a,b\}$.

Sure, convergence is not guaranteed. Take, for example, $\sqrt{x}$ on $[a,b]=[0,4]$. The slope $m=(f(b)-f(a))/(b-a)$ is $1/2$, so the algorithm proceeds by moving from initial point along the line with this slope until it intersects $y=0$; then repeat. This is problematic because for any starting point other than $4$, the intersection happens in the negative territory. Even if the function was defined there, who knows what it would do.

To estimate the speed of convergence, suppose $x_n\to x^*$ where $f(x^*)=0$. Generically, $f'(x^*)$ will not be equal to $m$. Therefore, the prediction $x_{n+1}$ will miss $x^*$ by an amount comparable to $|x_n-x^*|$; this is linear convergence rate.

Answer (score 0):

Provided that the estimated derivative is of the same sign as the actual derivative and no less than half its magnitude, then the convergence is guaranteed (provided you start close enough) and is linear. This can be easily proven by recognizing the problem is of the form $x_{n+1}=\Phi(x_n)$, which is fixed-point iteration. Computing $\Phi'(x)$ will then tell you what you need to know.

Tangentially related, it is interesting to note that the modified Newton method which uses the same estimated derivative repeatedly is not completely novel. In fact, it is often used in the [higher order case](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3825840/272831), where recomputing the Jacobian and inverting it can be very time consuming.